# GET request returns [ object Object] in django framework

Tags: javascript, django, rest

I have successfully created an API using django framework, and http://127.0.0.1:8000/tuto/users/ in the browser get me the user list,
Now i want to dislay it with on my web page, yet it returns [ object Object]

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="users">
      <p>No users are available.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.get("/tuto/users/").success(function (data) {
        window.alert(data)
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the alert message of [object Object]

Comment: show us the Python code since the problem most probably lies on the backend side

Comment: You need to convert the object/instance into some data format like json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because you are displaying the entire object, instead of just some of its properties.
Try changing `window.alert(data)` to

> window.alert(data.name)

Change name property to something you have in your user class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the JSON data returned by your API in textual form, you can also do:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

### Better ways to view your API data during development

While The above can help during development, there are better ways than `window.alert()`, e.g. if you use `console.log(data)` you'll get a navigable tree view of your object in your browser console.

The network tab of your browser can also provide an intelligible view of your data when it's received from your Django API.